# C++ Recursion stack

Tags: c++, recursion

I'm confused how Recursion works in this example.  If 'ABC\n' is inputted, CBA is outputted.  If someone could step through the process I would greatly appreciate it.

1. In main(), ReverseLine() is called
2. local automtic myInput takes in 'ABC\n'
3. Then it checks myInput for '\n' and EOF, this is where I start getting confused

I think it says, A != '\n' and A != EOF so ReverseLine() is called again, but then what???

How does the recursion work, I just want to understand the process

THANKS

```
    using namespace std;

    void ReverseLine(){
       int myInput;

       myInput = cin.get();

       if (myInput != '\n' && myInput != EOF)
        ReverseLine();

       if (myInput != EOF)
        cout.put(myInput);
    }

    int main(){

       ReverseLine();
       return 0;

    }
```

Comment: You tagged this question C, but it's a C++ program.

Comment: Did you try to use a debugger (e.g. `gdb` on Linux), and to single-step (the `step` command of `gdb`), and backtrace the debugged execution of your program? Explaining recursion may be difficult, and it depends a lot on your cultural & scientific background.

Comment: Yes, this looks as if it will not reverse anything, but instead will keep asking for a new string forever.

Comment: No, it does work. Maybe you don't understand recursion either ;)

Comment: @HewWolff: Are you running this under Windows? Reading from cmd line / shell heavily depends on Std Lib implementation and OS.

Comment: Far as I can tell, program should work as written. :-)

Comment: @Hew Wolff: no, it looks as if it will reverse the string.  This is probably the simplest example of recursion that I have ever seen.

Comment: Oops, sorry, you are correct.  I get it now.

Comment: I think it would be fun, when running this, to hold down a key and see how long it takes to overflow the stack.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you call ReverseLine, it reads a character. If the character isn't a newline or EOF, it calls itself again (recurses) to read the next character until it encounters a newline at which point it prints the character it just read, then returns to ReverseLine which prints the character it read and so forth until it returns to the initial call to ReverseLine, prints the first character read, then exits.

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps expanding it will help you understand?

```
void ReverseLine() {
   int myInput = 'a'

   if (myInput != '\n' && myInput != EOF) {
       int myInput = 'b'

       if (myInput != '\n' && myInput != EOF) {
           int myInput = 'c'

           if (myInput != '\n' && myInput != EOF) {
               int myInput = '\n'
               if (myInput != '\n' && myInput != EOF)
                   ReverseLine(); // doesn't get called
               cout.put(myInput);
           }
           if (myInput != EOF)
               cout.put(myInput);
       }

       if (myInput != EOF)
        cout.put(myInput);
   }

   if (myInput != EOF)
    cout.put(myInput);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Recursion, as Basile said, can be hard to understand. This example relies on the local variable concept. It will go to the end of the recursivity layer, and then start printing the local variable `myInput` from deepest recursive call to the first.

Let's suppose you input "123". Each indentation is a new local scope for `ReverseInput()`.

```
myInput = 1
ReverseLine()
  myInput = 2
  ReverseLine()
    myInput = 3
    ReverseLine()
      myInput = \n
    prints 3
  prints 2
prints 1
```

This is a common trick to do things the reverse way.

Answer (score 1):

It's really very simple. The ReverseLine function prints its output *before* it returns. Here is the sequence of events, if **ABC\n* is typed in

```
1. First call to ReverseLine.
1.a **A** is typed.
1.b myInput is not equal to **\n or EOF**, so
   2. Second call to ReverseLine
   2.a **B** is typed.
   2.b myInput is not equal to **\n** or **EOF**, so
      3. Third call to ReverseLine
      3.a **C** is typed.
      3.b myInput is not equal to **\n** or **EOF**, so
         4. Fourth call to ReverseLine
         4.a **\n** is typed.
         4.b myInput is equal to **\n**, so
         4.c ReverseLine is **not** called
         4.d myInput is **not** equal to **EOF**, so
         4.e myInput (**\n**) is printed
         4.f Fourth call to ReverseLine returns
      3.c myInput is **not** equal to **EOF**, so
      3.d myInput (**C**) is printed
      3.e Third call to ReverseLine returns
   2.c myInput is **not** equal to **EOF**, so
   2.d myInput (**B**) is printed
   2.e Second call to ReverseLine returns
1.c myInput is **not** equal to **EOF**, so
1.d myInput (**A**) is printed
1.e First call to ReverseLine returns
```

And then the program ends.